# How we can find where the file saved in phone after downloading in phone and share via whatsapp swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, file, urlsession

When user click on file link in webview I'm getting the url and through url session downloading the url but don't know this is  the correct way for saving the file in mobile in particular directory. When user open whatsapp and I want this file in files folder. After downloading the file want to tell the user that file downloaded.

```
static func loadFileAsync(url: URL, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void)
    {
        let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        
        let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
        
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path)
        {
            print("File already exists [\(destinationUrl.path)]")
            completion(destinationUrl.path, nil)
        }
        else
        {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:
                                            {
                data, response, error in
                if error == nil
                {
                    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                    {
                        if response.statusCode == 200
                        {
                            if let data = data
                            {
                                if let _ = try? data.write(to: destinationUrl, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
                                {
                                    completion(destinationUrl.path, error)
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    completion(destinationUrl.path, error)
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                completion(destinationUrl.path, error)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(destinationUrl.path, error)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Here you can see that I'm opening file through webView now i want when user opens file in webview file will download and saved in phone and share via whatsapp
[File open through url in webView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POXrN.png)

Comment: If you are using FileManager to save the file, definitely you can save the file name in DB to get back that file from FileManager.

Comment: @nitin.agam sorry I don't get your point can you show me code?